# Firefox contentEditable div focus issues

Tags: html, css, firefox, focus, contenteditable

I am using `contentEditable` div tags on my website and I have noticed a weird issue when using Firefox.

**Here is example source code:**

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div contentEditable="true" style="margin-left:auto; 
         margin-right:auto; height:200px; width:200px; border-style:solid; 
         border-color:black; border-width:1px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Here are the steps to reproduce.**

1. `contentEditable` has focus and cursor
   is blinking within the div, but
   there is NO text in the div
2. user click on the `contentEditable`
   div
3. the div still shows focus, but there
   is now NO blinking cursor, and the
   user cannot enter input into the div

I have reproduced this error with Firefox 3.6.3 on Ubuntu, and Firefox 3.5 on Windows XP. It does not happen with Chrome.

Any ideas about why this is happening and what to do to fix it?

**EDIT:**  One possible work around might be to manually set where the cursor is. Does anyone know how to do this? I've been searching online, but it doesn't look like there is anything W3 supported.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a Firefox bug. You should report this to Mozilla.

Comment: You should *not* report it to Mozilla because 3.6.3 makes no pretense about being fully HTML5-compliant, and is also not the latest version.  Try updating your Firefox installations first.  P.S.  Do you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your file?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, are you making an `INPUT FORM`?

Comment: it is for an application where the users input will be parsed and modified (ex. certain words will turn bold after the user types them in) I can't use textarea or other input tags because they don't allow markup within the text area.

I can accept that this is a firefox bug, but is there anything I can do besides hope my users dont have firefox 3.6.3 or earlier installed?

Comment: I just replicated the issue in google tasks. I guess if it's good enough for google, it is good enough for me?

Comment: I try with Fierfox 3.6.6 on Mac OSX, same issue and also when you click for first time there's no blinking cursor. With Chrome everything works fine.

Comment: @banzaimonkey: HTML5 is not the issue here. If there is inconsistent and confusing behaviour and it exists in the current version then I'd imagine Mozilla will want to know. Also, HTML5 is not finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by using UTF "Zero-width space". In PHP, it's the following escaped double-quote:

> "\xE2\x80\x8B"

You can then escape it using: trim($string, " \xE2\x80\x8B")

When this invisible character is preloaded in the editable div, this bug will disappear.

I use UTF-8 encoding for my page and also source file (and database... everything)

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `&nbsp;` into `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me too, sometimes it works, sometimes not. definately a bug i'd say. you could try inserting a hidden character, it seems to start blinking once there's some text.